# asp.net session issue in windows tab?

Tags: asp.net, session

I have an asp.net web application consisting of admin and customer portal and in this application there is a requirement i.e.  admin is allowed to login into customer portal and perform some specific task on his/her behalf. For this admin search all the customers and a link is provided in the grid upon clicking the link the admin portal passes custId in entryped format and dectrypt in patient portal and allowed to login and set all the respective sessions.

The issue I am facing right now is when  admin select multiple customer in new tab/window the session of the last selected customer is being overridden by the one selected earlier.

I am aware this is a techenical limitation when using Inproc sessionstate, wondering if there is any alternate solution to this issue.

Any suggestion/help on this would be of gr8 help.

Comment: Are you saying that admin is able to login a several customers at once? not just one customer at a time? I see that you're opening new tabs with each customer click in the table, right?

Comment: Well I am allowing admin to open one customer at a time and I have achieved this by encryption/decryption now the new challenge is that if the encrypted url is saved and opened from outside it is accessible how do I prevent that.

Comment: By adding current session ID to the encrypted URL. If one would then copy URL to another browser session it simply wouldn't work.

Comment: session Id is different for admin and customer portal, don't think it would work?